# how to Achieve this one object have two master details relationships records

Tags: relationships, admin

how to Achieve this one object have two master  details relationships records  i want more ...how i achieve this...using rollupsummary

Please xplain briefly

Comment: You can only have two master-detail relationships on a single object.

Answer (score 0):

As Martin mentioned, you cannot create more than 2 master detail relationships on an object. Thats a limitation enforced by the platform.

However there are other ways to implement this

1. Create a lookup relationship and make it required from the layout ( I would not advice to mark it required at field level, as it might affect existing implementation)
2. Create a field to track rollups from child lookups
3. Write a trigger to on child object to modify parent field value on Insert, Update, Delete, Undelete etc.

Cheers.